# Can anonymized data be collected under GDPR without consent?

Tags: internet, software, privacy, gdpr, human-rights

I am having an Android App in which I want to track the usage of the app. But the usage will not have anyone identity for eg. I would collect one user used my app for around 10 minutes but who is that user I will have no clue.

Do I need to take a consent under GDPR before collecting those kind of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need consent provided that the real person using your app indeed cannot be identified (other than by employing forensic technologies).

Source — [Recital 26: Not applicable to anonymous data](https://gdpr-info.eu/recitals/no-26/).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what data you track. If, based on that data, user can be identified then those are "information concerning an identified or identifiable natural person" which falls under GDPR.

[Check this for reference](https://iapp.org/news/a/looking-to-comply-with-gdpr-heres-a-primer-on-anonymization-and-pseudonymization/) and [this](https://dataprivacylab.org/projects/identifiability/paper1.pdf):

> As a well known study shows, it’s possible to personally identify 87 percent of the U.S. population based on just three data points: five-digit ZIP code, gender, and date-of-birth.